Should Angular version 15.2.9 still be used for applications after the LTS is no longer given?
as mentioned in the title, the question of this post is:
should Angular version 15.2.9 still be used for applications after the LTS is no longer given?
https://angular.dev/reference/releases
When should this version be upgraded?
Regards - Marco
I have read this page: https://angular.dev/reference/releases

What is your motivation? Is there active development in the applications?

end of life versions are no longer getting security updates. so it is a bit dangerous to live on old unpatched versions. but for FE technologies is not as dangerous as for server side ones

@JSON Derulo - a WebApp (FullCalendar) was created/used under Angular 15.2.9 - the development of the application has been completed and the application is currently going into production - is reachable from the Internet

@Andrei - the WebApp is reachable from the Internet - so I assume that the version should be upgraded ...

not crucial for FE apps. there wasn't any security problems fixed since 15.2.9 afaik
